# Simple htaccess rewrite rule error 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set a simple htaccess rule, but is not working. 
I think the problem is with the `?` and `=` characters?

The code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
ErrorDocument 404 /php/404redirect.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^productos.php?id=([0-9]+)$ /?view=productos&id=$1 [L,NE,B,QSA]
```

This always give me error 404.

What I want is redirect all requests from:
`www.example.com/productos.php?id=X`
to
`www.example.com/?view=productos&id=X`

Comment: You're using a rewrite rule but you mention that you want it to redirect, what do you actually want it to do? Redirect it or interpret a URL in a different way to how it displays?

Comment: Yes i think a redirect is better. What i finally want to show the user is a rewrite like: /productos/id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^productos.php /?view=productos [L,NE,B,QSA]`

or if you want to redirect

`RewriteRule ^productos.php /?view=productos [L,NE,B,QSA,R=301]`

Answer (score 3):

Querystring is not part of match in RewriteRule directive, to redirect query strings, you need to use RewriteCond one of the following options :

**option 1**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?id=([^&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?view-product&id=%1? [NC,L,R]
```

**option 2**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ /?view-product&id=%1? [NC,L,R]
```

We use an empty question mark **?** at the end of the target url to discard the old query strings, otherwise these query strings get appened to the target url by default.

Change the **R** to **R=301** if you want to make the redirection permanent.